# MySql order by count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, having

The task is list of countries that has more than 10 customers
I'm trying to show only the values that count > 10 in the table

I've tried this but its not filtering the table:

```
select co.country, count(*) from sakila.country as co
inner join city as ci on co.country_id = ci.country_id
inner join address as ad on ci.city_id = ad.city_id
inner join customer as cu on cu.address_id = ad.address_id
group by co.country
order by count(*) > 10;
```

Comment: Instead of your `order by` clause, instead use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By only showing the values with a count greater 10, you need to use `having`. `having` needs to be used, when you want to filter your results of a aggregate function, e.g. count, sum.

```
select co.country, count(*)
from sakila.country as co
inner join city as ci on co.country_id = ci.country_id
inner join address as ad on ci.city_id = ad.city_id
inner join customer as cu on cu.address_id = ad.address_id
group by co.country
having count(*) > 10;
order by count(*);
```

If you still want to order your results by the count, you still need to have the `order by` at the en